# What chapters/episode are the Hore Herb & Horedan Flower in To LOVE-Ru?

Tags: to-love-ru

The [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_LOVE%E3%82%8B_-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%89%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8B-#%E5%AE%87%E5%AE%99%E6%A4%8D%E7%89%A9) of *To LOVE-Ru* mentions two out of many types of plants:

1. Hore Herb (ホレ草)
2. Horedan Flower (ホレダンの花)

I tried looking in the manga of both the original and sequel *To LOVE-Ru Darkness* but I can't find it.

What chapter/episode each one of those plants was in?

Answer (score 1):

**The *Hore* Herb (ホレ草) is inferred in *To LOVE-Ru* volume 5 chapter 40** and **the *Horedan* Flower (ホレダンの花) is from an original scenario on a booklet packaged with The First Edition of *To LOVE-Ru Darkness 2nd* BD/DVD.**

In volume 5 chapter 40 of *To LOVE-Ru* (凶悪バレンタイン, A Brutal Valentine' Day),

> when Rito asked Mikado-sensei what happened to the students, she replied that she had told Lala to add an aphrodisiac from a plant from Planet Hore in her chocolate.
>
>  御門: 催淫効果のある**ホレ星の薬草**を入れるように教えちゃったのよね
>
>  <sup>([The original panel in Japanese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFL5Z.png))</sup>

Regarding [The First Edition of *To LOVE-Ru Darkness 2nd* BD/DVD](https://www.amazon.co.jp/LOVE%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%89%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8B-%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8D%E3%82%B92nd-Blu-ray-BOX-%E5%88%9D%E5%9B%9E%E4%BB%95%E6%A7%98%E7%89%88/dp/B072X87N4T), this is the booklet.

[image: the booklet from the BD Box]

However, there's no review/further information about the content of the booklet, aside from the Japanese Wikipedia putting a footnote for the source of *Horedan* Flower.